# Formik & Mobx setting initial values from API

Tags: reactjs, mobx, formik

Allow me to preface this by saying that I am new to react, I have looked at other posts, and I am still unable to fix the issue.

My issue is as follows, I am trying to create a form, which allows the user to input their reps, sets, and the weight used, for each exercise that is part of their workout. However, if the user tries to input anything it acts like a read only field. My suspicion being that something is wrong with how I am setting the initial value. In my WorkoutStore.ts, I define a computed value called exercisesForForm as follows:

```
 @computed get exercisesForForm() {
        const data = this.exercises.map((e) => ({
            name: e.name,
            id: e.id,
            sets: e.sets,
            reps: e.reps,
            weight: e.weight

        }));

        return data;
    }
```

When I console log it, I can clearly see that it is being properly set. However, if I try to access it or anything it keeps complaining about it being undefined. So the main question really is: what is the correct way to define initial values that are received from an API endpoint. If this was just a form specifically for one entity (say like one exercise) this would be much easier since then it would a simple 1 : 1 mapping of the data to the elements in the form

I am trying to define my form as follows:

```
const rootStore = useContext(RootStoreContext);
    const {getExercises, exercises, exercisesForForm} = rootStore.workoutStore;

    useEffect(() => {

        if(match.params.workoutId) {
            getExercises(match.params.workoutId);
        }
    }, [getExercises, match.params.workoutId])


<Formik key={uuid()} onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} initialValues={exercisesForForm} enableReinitialize={true}>
                {({
                    handleSubmit,
                    handleChange,
                    values
                }) => (
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    {exercises.map((exercise, index) => 
                        (
                            <Fragment key={exercise.id}>
                                <Header>{exercise.name}</Header>
                                    <Form.Row>
                                        <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                            <Form.Label>Sets</Form.Label>
                                            <Form.Control key={uuid()} type="number" name='sets' value={0} onChange={handleChange}/>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                    </Form.Row>

                                    <Form.Row>
                                        <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                            <Form.Label>Reps</Form.Label>
                                            <Form.Control key={uuid()} type="number" name='reps' onChange={handleChange}/>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                    </Form.Row> 
                                    <Form.Row>
                                        <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                            <Form.Label>Weight</Form.Label>
                                            <Form.Control key={uuid()} type="number" name='weight' onChange={handleChange}/>
                                        </Form.Group>
                                    </Form.Row>       
                            </Fragment>                              
                        )
                        )}
                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='04'>
                                <Button content="Submit" floated='right' type="submit"/>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form.Row>     
                        </Form>
                    )}</Formik>
```

A follow up question to this would be, how to properly define the name component of the form? In MVC.NET (Which is what I am most familiar with web wise) I would simply define an array and dynamically create the inputs using something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Answers[i].Answer, new { type = "text" })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling, and experimentation, and rereading of the docs I was able to figure it out. I changed my code to look as follows:

```
<Formik key={uuid()} onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}  enableReinitialize={true} initialValues={exercisesForForm}
                        render={({values, handleChange, handleSubmit}) => (
                            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                        {values.map((e, index) => (
                                            <Fragment key={index}>
                                                <Header>{e.name}</Header>
                                                <Form.Row>
                                                    <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                                        <Form.Label>Sets</Form.Label>
                                                        <Form.Control key={`${index}_sets`} type='number' name={`[${index}].sets`} value={(e.sets)} onChange={handleChange} />
                                                    </Form.Group>
                                                </Form.Row>
                                                <Form.Row>
                                                    <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                                        <Form.Label>Reps</Form.Label>
                                                        <Form.Control key={`${index}_reps`} type='number' name={`[${index}].reps`} value={(e.reps)} onChange={handleChange} />
                                                    </Form.Group>
                                                </Form.Row>
                                                <Form.Row>
                                                    <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                                        <Form.Label>Weight</Form.Label>
                                                        <Form.Control key={`${index}_weight`} type='number' name={`[${index}].weight`} value={(e.weight)} onChange={handleChange} />
                                                    </Form.Group>
                                                </Form.Row>
                                            </Fragment>
                                        )

                                    )}
                                )}
                                <Form.Row>
                                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='04'>
                                        <Button content="Submit" floated='right' type="submit"/>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Form.Row>
                            </Form>
                        )}
                    />
```

Couple of things to note: I am using the `values` property in order to access the initial values; also I am using the index to set the name of the field. I think that was the missing link that ties it together.